# Indexing Hash Bang #! Content Using Google Search Appliance (GSA)

Tags: google-search-appliance, hashbang

Has anyone had success indexing content that contains #! (Hashbang) in the URL? If so, how did you do it?

We have a third party help center of ours that we are hosting that requires the use of #! in the URL, however, we need the ability to index this content within our GSA. We are using version 7.0.14.G.238 of our GSA

Here's an example of one of our help articles with a hashbang in the URL:

> /templates/selfservice/example/#!portal/201500000001006/article/201500000006039/Resume-and-Cover-Letter-Reviews

I understand #! requires JavaScript, not the most friendly SEO in the world and many popular sites (Facebook, Twitter, etc.) deprecated the use of it.

Answer (score 0):

While some Javascript content is indexed, if you want to make sure there is absolutely content in the index for this site you have two options. Either make sure the site is non-JS friendly which is supported in a lot of JS frontend sites, or alternatively use a content feed to push the data into the GSA instead. Turn off JS in your browser and access the site and see if content links are created.

If you have access to the database, you could just send the content straight in, however read up here: http://www.google.com/support/enterprise/static/gsa/docs/admin/72/gsa_doc_set/feedsguide/ on feeds which can send data straight in, or possibly read up on connectors in general https://support.google.com/gsa/topic/2721859?hl=en&ref_topic=2707841

Comment: Does the GSA support "?_escaped_fragment_=" that Google.com supports?

Comment: I read here escaped_fragment won't work with latest version 7.2 or older version of GSA. I was in the middle of configuring our site to use seo4ajax.com so we can take advantage of this google spec, but since the GSA doesn't support it at this time (I'm told its in development from Google Support) then my approach is a bust.

https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/google-search-appliance-help/wWIDIQ4BDgM